# RSA: Proving that $p+q-1 < 3 \sqrt{N}$, where N = pq and p,q are prime?

Tags: rsa, cryptanalysis

I'm doing some research into attacks on the RSA cryptosystem and have stumbled across Wiener's attack. Within the proof there exists the statement  "$p+q-1 < 3\sqrt{N}$".
No proof is given for this, and I can't seem to figure out why this statement holds. Could anyone help me figure this out or point me towards the relevant theorems?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is likely an assumption on the sizes of $p$ and $q$ that you haven't listed in your question that exists in the description. For example, [Boneh's description](https://crypto.stanford.edu/~dabo/papers/RSA-survey.pdf) of Wiener's attack has that $q<p<2q$.

With that assumption, we can prove the inequality.

We know that

$$p+q < 2q+q$$
$$p+q < 3q$$

Furthermore, since $N=pq$ and $p>q$, we have that $\sqrt{N} > q$, or $3\sqrt{N} > 3q$. So

$$p+q < 3q < 3\sqrt{N}$$

In your inequality, you have $p+q-1$ which is clearly smaller than $p+q$, so everything works out, $p+q-1 < 3\sqrt{N}$.

Comment: To expand on the first sentence: An assumption on the sizes of $p$ and $q$ relative to each other is not only likely, but *necessary*: otherwise, $p=2$ and $q=17$ and similar highly "unbalanced" cases would provide a counterexample.

Comment: You are very much right! I'd gotten too focussed on one specific part to actually go back and read the attack specifications, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I'm thinking that is not true. Because if we have $p=67$ and $q=3$ then $N=201$ and $p+q-1=69$ and so we have  inconsistence.

Comment: as noted by mike, you apparantly need to assume $q<p<2q$ (which is always the case with standard RSA keys)

Comment: Right, I just look the question. Sorry